# Anybody's had any luck with asp.net MVC 6's new html markup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It seems not many people are testing asp.net vNext MVC 6 as I can't dig out much resource. I am interested, so I have been testing it these days.

In Scott's [article](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5), he says that

So instead of writing this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

You can instead write this:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="UserName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried it in an azure virtual machine running Windows Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2015 CTP. The new html markup has not worked. I get null values upon postback for those input fields using the new syntax such as `input asp-for` and `span asp-validation-for` also fails to spit out the validation message I am expecting. And I can't find any updates. Am I missing anything that makes this new markup fail? Thanks.

Comment: I fired up a new web app project in 2015 RC and was seeing markup like this: http://i.imgur.com/RGTx3mz.png

Comment: Right, those are the new syntax Scott talks about in his article.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure to include the helper library just below your model declaration

```
@addtaghelper "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

Comment: Ah, that  must be it. Let me login to azure, start up (slowly) the vm and, launch the vs2015 (slowly) and re-test it.

Comment: Added that line like you said, but when building, getting this on that line: `Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers'. ...`. I am trying to nuget the dll.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Although it complains that `'ModelOnly' does not exist in the current context` for this line: `<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>`

Comment: BTW, I think this new markup is a big step forward, razor is good, but still can get rather messy. I am sure people struggled about when to use `@:, @(blah blah), <text>blah blah</text>`

Comment: try asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" (this is only a guess, but I know that ValidationSummary.All gives you all the validation errors).

Comment: Again, that was it. Thanks. I love this new markup. Much cleaner.